# Help finding an article from Hearot u-Veurim in 2013

Tags: jewish-books, chabad

can anyone help me find an article cited as:

R. Chaim Rapoport, “Sipurim Temuhim . . .,” Hearot u-Veurim 33:2 (2013), pp. 55-67

…in note 7 [here](https://seforimblog.com/2017/11/the-rogochover-and-more/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it in the Haoros archive [here](http://www.haoros.com/archive/)

If you scroll down to the year תשע"ג - 5773 and select Kovetz no. 1041 and select the Adobe Acrobat version and head to p.55 it is there in all its glory!

Happy reading!

Comment: Thank you! I'd never have traced issue 33 to number 1041!

Comment: No problem! Enjoy!

Comment: Nice find! Interesting topic also!